# Solo una parte del comentario aparece en la base de datos, la segunda parte no

Tags: java, android, firebase

No sé lo que estoy haciendo mal, pero cuando un usuario comenta en una de tus publicaciones tu recibes una notificación al fragmento y también obviamente el comentario se guarda en Firebase. El problema es que no está apareciendo el ni la notificación en el fragmento ni en la base de datos. La demás información sí, pero el comentario no. Me refiero a esta linea `hashMap2.put("comment", "responded: " + mAddComment.getText().toString());`. Lo que si aparece es `hashMap2.put("comment", "responded: "` esta parte, pero esta parte no `+ mAddComment.getText().toString());`.

El problema lo tengo en el metodo respond(); en el segundo HashMap `HashMap2`.

Alguien sabe por qué puede que no aparezca?

```
public class ResponseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mAddComment;
    ImageView mImageProfile;
    TextView mPost;

    private ResponseAdapter mResponseAdapter;
    private List<Response> mResponseList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    String mCommentId;
    String mPublisherId;
    String mPostId;
    String mNotificationId;

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mAddComment = findViewById(R.id.add_comment);
        mImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        mPost = findViewById(R.id.post_comment);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Responses");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> finish());

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
        mResponseAdapter = new ResponseAdapter(this, mResponseList, mCommentId);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mResponseAdapter);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mCommentId = intent.getStringExtra("commentid");
        mPublisherId = intent.getStringExtra("publisherid");
        mPostId = intent.getStringExtra("postid");

        mPost.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mAddComment.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ResponseActivity.this, "Can't send empty comments", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                respond();
            }
        });

        getImage();
        readComments();
    }

    private void respond() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Responses").child(mCommentId);

        mNotificationId = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("response", mAddComment.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("publisher", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("responseid", mNotificationId);
        hashMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        hashMap.put("commentid", mCommentId);

        reference.child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap);
        mAddComment.setText("");

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap2.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap2.put("comment", "responded: " + mAddComment.getText().toString());
        hashMap2.put("postid", mPostId);
        hashMap2.put("ispost", true);
        hashMap2.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
        hashMap2.put("commentid", mCommentId);

        if (!mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(mPublisherId))
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(mPublisherId).child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No aparece porque el string está vacío. Lo procesas para `hashMap`:

```
hashMap.put("response", mAddComment.getText().toString());
```

Y luego borras su contenido al hacer:

```
mAddComment.setText("");
```

Antes de llenar `hashMap2`.

Debería bastar con:

```
private void respond() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Responses").child(mCommentId);

    mNotificationId = reference.push().getKey();

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("response", mAddComment.getText().toString());
    hashMap.put("publisher", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
    hashMap.put("responseid", mNotificationId);
    hashMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    hashMap.put("commentid", mCommentId);

    reference.child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap);

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap2.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
    hashMap2.put("comment", "responded: " + mAddComment.getText().toString());
    hashMap2.put("postid", mPostId);
    hashMap2.put("ispost", true);
    hashMap2.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
    hashMap2.put("commentid", mCommentId);

    mAddComment.setText("");

    if (!mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(mPublisherId))
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(mPublisherId).child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap2);
}
```

Comment: Tío, muchas gracias. Sí que aparece ahora, pero POR QUE¨?? No entiendo como lo tenia antes en su antigua posición porque no aparecia??? No entiendo cual es la diferencia tenerlo allí si mAddComment es un variable global...

Comment: Tienes un campo de texto en tu interfaz de usuario (`EditText mAddComment`). Éste tiene un texto que el usuario introduce. En el momento en el que haces `mAddComment.setText("");` limpias el campo, es decir, estás estableciendo en ese campo de texto el contenido a un string vacio `""`, por lo que pierdes la información que hubiera en ese campo. Al hacer después `mAddComment.getText()` ese método te devuelve el texto que tiene, que es `""` (un `String` vacío), ya que es lo que pusiste con `mAddComment.setText("");`. En la solución, el campo se limpia después de recuperar la información.

Comment: Vale tío, gracias por la explicación. Entiendo